# Error with installing software

Tags: 14.04, software-center, plugins

[image]

I just Install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and install the required software, its smooth . But in the mean time, I am trying to install all software by **Aptik** . and this time , a problem occur. After this , while I installing any software by **command line** an error message will occur **( just as marked as yellow box in the fig)**.
Similar problem also occurs for installing **pulgin** . Then there appears a box for repair the same, but while I click for **Repair** , another error message will occur.

What can I do for such problem. Please help me. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

What is inside the yellow box is just a warning. I think that if you trust the package you can just type "Y" when promted to proceed instalation of your package.

Comment: If you trust the package, that means waiting until you're sure you've actually received the trusted package instead of a possibly corrupted or malicious version of it that you shouldn't trust.